# AndEngine. Execute a sequence on collision

Tags: android, andengine

I wanna in andEngine execute a sequence (sprite animation) when sprite collides with something. Tryed to define the sequenceEntityModifier in the IUpdateHandler but the sequence doesn't execute.

Any suggestion about how to achive this ? Where to put my animation code ?

```
sprite.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
        if(sprite.collidesWith(shape)) {


            // this will not work
            final SequenceEntityModifier enemyModifier = new SequenceEntityModifier(
            ...
            )
            // this too
            sprite.setScale(0.5f);

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void reset() {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are not using Box2D, so register this `IUpdateHandler` to your sprite:

```java
sprite.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
        if(sprite.collidesWith(shape)) {
            //animation here
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() {
    }
});
```

Comment: I use BOX2D and use the IUpdateHandler..but if I put where you wrote: animation here. this lines.. spriteball.setscale(0.5f) or even if I define a Sequence with modifiers it will not animate even though the code is executed.

Comment: If you are using Box2D, use `ContactListener` instead.

Comment: how can i collide sprite with AnimatedSprite?